# How to use Lombok annotations for optional configuration values

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, lombok

for my application there will be two different configuration files structure depending on the situation and I am not sure how to write code that will work regardless of which file it uses. Right now, I get an error saying that the some of the configuration values are missing in the configuration files but that is my use case. I am using lombok and springboot. The following is the structure of my configuration files.

```
-- configurationfile1.yml
prefix:
   one: string

-- configurationfile2.yml
    prefix:
       one: string
       optionalPrefix:
         two: string
```

The optionalPrefix could be defined or could not be defined. The following is what my configuration class looks like.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
@Configuration
public class config {

   @Getter @Value("${prefix.one}")
   private String one;

   @Getter @Value("${prefix.optionalPrefix.two}")
   private String two;
```

However when I run this code without the optionalPrefix, it throws an error saying that it can't find it. What's the best way to only define the variable "two" if that configuration is defined in the configuration file? Is there a way I can set the variable "two" to null if it's not defined? Is there a best way to this?

Comment: You're just throwing annotations at things. `@ConfigurationProperties` should normally be on a separate class, and it definitely shouldn't be combined with `@Value`. Examine the Spring examples and follow them.

Comment: how do I fix the issue I asked about?

Comment: The configuration file changes depending on which environment it runs on. I can’t have separate classes for each environment